# ReactNative App build failing with Flipper error

Tags: ios, react-native, flipper

I have inherited a ReactNative app, that i need to get up and running in dev.
I am completely a noob.

I think i am close.

When I run

```
npm run ios
```

I get the error

> CompileC /Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/tpp-cdzrkyfpwzsixefrnjryzmdnucct/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphoneos/FlipperKit.build/Objects-normal/arm64/FlipperPlatformWebSocket.o /Users/me/Projects/tpp/ios/Pods/FlipperKit/iOS/FlipperKit/FlipperPlatformWebSocket.mm normal arm64 objective-c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler (in target 'FlipperKit' from project 'Pods')

After some googling i have added in the project root the file react-native.config.js with the contents

```
module.exports = {
  dependencies: {
    ...(process.env.CI // or `process.env.NO_FLIPPER` for RN@0.71.x and above
    ? { 'react-native-flipper': { platforms: { ios: null } } }
    : {}),
},
  project: {
    ios: {},
    android: {},
  },
};
```

The last thing the article said i needed to do was

> You can specify NO_FLIPPER=1 when installing your iOS pods, to instruct React Native not to install Flipper. Typically, the command would look like this:
>
> from the root folder of the react native project
>
> bundle exec pod install --project-directory=ios

This is where i am getting in the weeds.

Where does this command "bundle exec pod install --project-directory=ios" go, since i am running "npm run ios" ??

Comment: Run => rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData
and delete the pod folder and podfile.lock and then again install pods it will resolve your issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`bundle exec pod install --project-directory=ios`

It is similar to `cd ios && pod install`. It means, you have to run this before `npm run ios`. You can use this instead. But for above command, you have to run this command from root directory of your project. As you can see in your folder structure there will be `ios` folder. Here the full explanation of this command:-

`bundle exec`: This part of the command ensures that the pod command is executed within the context of a Ruby bundle. It's a way to ensure that the correct version of CocoaPods (if specified in the project's Gemfile) is used.

`pod install`: This is the CocoaPods command that installs the dependencies specified in the Podfile of the project. It resolves dependencies and downloads the necessary libraries.

`--project-directory=ios`: This flag specifies the directory where the Podfile is located. In this case, it's telling CocoaPods to look for the Podfile in the ios directory. This is useful in projects where the iOS code is organized into a subdirectory, commonly named ios.

Also the error, you are trying to solve. You have to follow these steps:-

`Method 1:`

```
Step 1: cd ios
Step 2: pod repo update
Step 3: pod install
```

move to method 2, if it won't work.

`Method 2:`

Step 1: If you are using a `react-native-flipper` your iOS build will fail when `NO_FLIPPER=1` is set.
because `react-native-flipper` depends on (FlipperKit,...) that will be excluded

To fix this you can also exclude `react-native-flipper` using a `react-native.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
  ..., // other configs
  dependencies: {
    ...(process.env.NO_FLIPPER
    ? { 'react-native-flipper': { platforms: { ios: null } } }
    : {}),
  }
};
```

Step 2: You have to run one of these commands from root directory of the project:

`NO_FLIPPER=1 bundle exec pod install --project-directory=ios`

or

`cd ios && NO_FLIPPER=1 pod install`